# DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined (found in field uid)

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

So I'm trying to make a signup form for an app, and everything seems to be working just fine except the fact that it throws an error. 
The data seems to appear in my database, but when i try "ng serve" the compiler give an error.

my browser console spits out the following statement:

> DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined (found in field uid)

This is the same thing as the title said.

```
"ERROR in src/app/core/auth.service.ts(57,11): error TS2740: Type '{ uid: any; email: any;
displayName: any; photoURL: any; }' is missing the following properties from type 'User': delete, emailVerified, getIdTokenResult, getIdToken, and 24 more."
```

I've tried looking for syntax errors, since I'm following a tutorial. Tried checking if there's no upper lower case etc.

The following is my auth.service.ts file

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { AngularFireAuth } from "angularfire2/auth";
import {
  AngularFirestore,
  AngularFirestoreDocument
} from "angularfire2/firestore";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import "rxjs/add/operator/switchMap";
import { User } from "firebase";
import { of } from "rxjs";

 interface user {
   uid: string;
   email: string;
   photoURL ? : string;
   displayName ? : string;
 }

 @Injectable()
 export class AuthService {
   user: Observable < user >

     constructor(
       private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
       private afs: AngularFirestore,
       private router: Router
     ) {
       this.user = this.afAuth.authState.switchMap(user => {
         if (user) {
           return this.afs.doc < User > ('users/${user.uid}').valueChanges();
         } else {
           return of(null)
         }
       })
     }

   emailSignIn(email: string, password: string) {
     return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
       .then(() => console.log("You have successfully signed in"))
       .catch(error => console.log(error.message))
   }

   emailSignUp(email: string, password: string) {
     return this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
       .then(user => this.updateUserData(user))
       .then(() => console.log("Welcome, your account has been created!"))
       .catch(error => console.log(error.message))
   }

   signOut() {
     return this.afAuth.auth.signOut()
       .then(() => {
         this.router.navigate(['/'])
       })
   }

   private updateUserData(user) {
     const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument < User > =
       this.afs.doc(`users/${user.uid}`)
     const data: User = {
       uid: user.uid,
       email: user.email || null,
       displayName: user.displayName,
       photoURL: user.photoURL
     }
     return userRef.set(data, {
       merge: true
     })
   }
 }
```

I just need to get rid of the error, so it wont throw me off in the future. In case something happens to the database in the future, and also for me to learn how to solve these kind of problems.

After in input a new user-email and a valid password, firebase registers the changes and stores it in its database, but for some reason im getting this nasty error, and i dont like seeing red underlined code.

Pretty much just making features for the signup page of the app im creating.

Thank you for any incoming help.

Comment: and which line is this error displayed in?

Comment: Should be line 57 where "const data: User = { }" data is underlined

Comment: yes I see it's line 57 in the error message, but which line is that in your code?

Comment: const data: User = {

Comment: Its line 57 both in the error and also in my code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your const `data` is not of type `User` interface provided by firebase. You can inspect the firebase `User` interface in the source code, and it includes properties like the error suggest, or read from official **[documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User)**.

you want to to use your interface you have created, i.e `user`:

```
const data: user = {
  uid: user.uid,
  email: user.email || null,
  displayName: user.displayName,
  photoURL: user.photoURL
}
```

That would mean that the doc you want is also of type `user`:

```
const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<user> = this.afs.doc(`users/${user.uid}`);
```

Also what you need to return from the signup, is `user.user`:

```
return this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then(user => this.updateUserData(user.user))
```

since `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` returns [promise of **`UserCredential`**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth.html#sign-inwith-email-and-password)

I see that you are using `User` as type in other places, so if you encounter other places with similar issues, it would be caused by the same.

As an addition I can mention, what user would the `firebase.User` be? Well, that is the user you get returned from:

```
this.afAuth.auth.currentUser
```

Comment: Ive tried to replace all the "User" with "user" and vice versa. 

Ive been able to get rid of the error, but now my browser console still states "DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined (found in field uid)"

Plus it is not showing up in my firebase database neither. But it creates the user
Can you give any further direction?

Comment: okay, that error actually means that the `user.uid` is `undefined` like error states. This is the `updateUserData` function that throws error when called after signup? Either way, need to debug why it is `undefined`.

Comment: wait, I think I noticed the issue.

Comment: check now. I suggest you always debug by console logging the data to see what it contains :) Also, if you have just started with this project, I would update angularfire, seems you are using an older version. Also you should move on to pipeable operators for your rxjs :)

Comment: Im kinda a newbie on this, any idea where i should place the stuff youre reffering to on the update of the answer

Comment: well I have just copied your code. So the only change I made was the change to the sign up function

Comment: Great, glad I could help! :)